# .deb packages won't install on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, deb

Whenever I download a .deb it open the new Ubuntu Software and the install button is completely non functioning. The packages are always from trusted sources such as the atom.io or visual studio code. Thus I go to terminal and try to install the package from there and the install is always incomplete, there are always some errors that come up.

I have reinstalled Ubuntu numerous times, because of other reasons, and in each fresh install I run into the same problem with installing .deb packages. My work around is that I add repo's and download them directly from there but I'd like to know if this is a bug with 17.04 or my machine in particular.

Comment: You should install via `sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
`

Comment: ... or via `gdebi-gtk` if you prefer a GUI interface.

Comment: I've noticed a similar problem with the USC. Haven't reported it as a bug, so you could if you wanted to.